# Run a cron job every 5 minutes between two times

Tags: cron, crontab

Is there a way to specify a job that runs every 5 minutes between some start time and some end time on business days in a crontab?

**Update**
I think it's relevant that my start and end times are not at round hours.  So, specifying 9-5 in the hour column isn't enough.  I want 9:30-17:30.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll have to do it piecewise:

```
30-59/5 9 * * * script.sh
*/5 10-16 * * * script.sh
0-30/5 17 * * * script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer](https://superuser.com/a/133462/53590) doesn't really work for you, for example because the script needs a large number of parameters or the invocation criteria are non-trivial (or not time-bound), then an alternative approach is to make a simple wrapper script, call the wrapper script at regular intervals, and have the wrapper script check the current time and invoke the main script.

For example:

```
#/bin/bash

# Check to see if we should run the script now.
HOUR=$(date +%H)
MINUTE=$(date +%M)
if test $HOUR -lt 9; then exit 0; fi
if test $HOUR -eq 9 -a $MINUTE -lt 30; then exit 0; fi
if test $HOUR -eq 17 -a $MINUTE -gt 30; then exit 0; fi
if test $HOUR -gt 17; then exit 0; fi

# All checks passed; we should run the script now.
exec script.sh ... long list of parameters ...
```

This allows for encoding execution criteria more complex than cron's syntax readily allows for, at the relatively small expense of invoking a shell and a separate script regularly.