# Run a script every minute between two times using launchd

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl

I'm trying to run a script every minute (or 20 seconds) between 06:30 and 10:30 every weekday using launchd. I have the script running every minute / X seconds now, but I don't know how to limit this to workdays between two defined times.

The question [Run a cron job every 5 minutes between two times](https://superuser.com/questions/133456/run-a-cron-job-every-5-minutes-between-two-times) give the answer for cron, but I'd like to do the same using launchd.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

`StartCalendarInterval` can also be an array of dictionaries like this: `for w in {1..5}; do for h in {6..11}; do echo "<dict><key>Weekday</key><integer>$w</integer><key>Hour</key><integer>$h</integer><key>Second</key><integer>0</integer></dict>"; done; done | pbcopy`.

You could also run the script every minute but exit it depending on the time or date:

```
weekday=$(date +%u)
hour=$(date +%-H)
min=$(date +%-M)    
[ $weekday -ge 6 ] && exit
[ $hour -le 5 -o $hour -eq 6 -a $min -le 29 ] && exit
[ $hour -ge 11 -o $hour -eq 10 -a $min -ge 31 ] && exit
```